# Android - PubNub - Pass the UUID or Username of a user with each sent message

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, uuid, pubnub

Hello
I've built an Android application that uses PubNub to create a chat channel between each user. I would like to be able to identify which users have sent which messages. Currently the login of my app is handled by Parse so each user has a unique username. I found some documentation and example code where rather than sending just the message string, an object was set up that contained the UUID and message string as two different objects that could then be extracted on the subscribe side but from what I could tell this was only in the PubNub javascript code not the Java code for Android.
Right now i'm thinking that the only way for me to do this is to attach the UUID/username to the beginning of my message string with a special character to seperate the UUID and the message and then split it up and read it in on the subscribe side.
 For example `String message = "uuidhere_messagehere";`. 
Is this the correct way to approach this or is there a better, more convenient way of doing this?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct - PubNub does not inject anything into your messages so you will need to include the *sender id* within each message that is published. Here's is a simple example of a JSON message you might publish:

```
{'sender_id':'user_333', 'msg':'this is my msg to you-hoo-hoo'}
```

Of course, the JSON message can have any key/value pairs you require.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will have a look into JSON